# Keeping /etc folder on a remote server

Tags: server, bazaar, etc, version-control

I have `etckeeper` with default configuration (bazaar as VCS). I want to keep this repository on the remote server (for example on Amazon EC2 or, if possible, on Dropbox/Box.net/Ubuntu One).

I tried to include `/etc` folder to `Ubuntu One` backup shedule. But the obvious problem is `root` privileges: some files could not be read and stored without `root` privileges.

So, how do I organize the proccess of keeping my local `/etc` repository to the remote server?

I thought about cron task, which would zip `/etc` folder into archive in my `/home` directory. But it seems to be bad workaround.

Comment: Can't you exclude the sensitive files somehow? That would seem a sensible solution.

Comment: there are too many of these files... It's hard to exclude all of them =)

Comment: I'm generally using `etckeeper` mostly locally and with `git`, not `bazaar`, but for all I remember there was no problem with exporting a bare `git` repo, putting it on a remote server, adding it locally as a remote and then pushing to it. Didn't try to automate this (i.e. make the push an automatic action triggered by a commit), but this shouldn't be that much of a problem.

Comment: Yes... It seems that the best way is to convert my repo from bazaar to git and automize pushing it to the remote server.

Comment: The only reason I would not just zip it into the Dropbox folder is you probably want multiple historic versions for in case something breaks and you don't realize it immediately and you backup strategy deletes all traces of it before you notice. I know Dropbox keeps history but I don't trust it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use and recommend [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/examples.html) for that.

```
sudo apt-get install rdiff-backup
```

assuming you have ssh access to the remote server:

```
sudo rdiff-backup /etc user@example.com::/remote-dir
```

[Then I would set up signing in with a ssh key.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)

Then you just need to run a cronjob as root. Put command in cron config file:

```
sudo echo "rdiff-backup /etc user@example.com::/remote-dir" > /etc/cron.daily/etc_backup
```

and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod u+x /etc/cron.daily/etc_backup
```

not sure if it is necessary to make it owned by root:

```
sudo chown root: /etc/cron.daily/etc_backup
```

**Alternatively** you can back it up to your dropbox directory.

```
rdiff-backup /etc ~/Dropbox
```